# New phonegap project failing with TypeError: undefined is not a function on line 1

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Trying to get phonegap to work on an iPhone. 
With a completely blank project, except for jsconsole for debbuging and the cordova.ios.js file, I keep getting errors as soon as the app loads:

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/19E49099-C481-44B4-8803-07A0390EA3B3/pplats.app/www/index.html:1link
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
```

I cant get anything more out of the stacktrace. Why could I be getting a TypeError? Completely running out of ideas here.

The HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="cordova.ios.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jsconsole.com/remote.js?79F01FAA-19A6-40C2-B32F-7FEF1D5E3998"></script>
</head>
<body>
testing......
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your project directory structure look like?

My guess is that this is related to the `src="cordova.ios.js"` link, have you tried specifying an absolute or root-relative (`/path-to-file/cordova.ios.js`) path to the js file?